Bonsai in the wall
I am looking for a movie. It has something to do with computers. Towards the end there is a scene in a pretty nice office. One of the main characters is on the phone and there is a beautiful bonsai behind a glass in the wall. It looks as if the bonsai is in a climate controlled environment, because it was shedding leaves.
EDIT after comment:
Well I saw on TV like 10 years ago. It is definitely made in the US. I think it took place on the west coast of the US. For some reason I keep on thinking it had to do with the Microsoft/Apple story. But it is not Pirates of Silicon Valley. 

Any additional information that may help to identify it? When did you see it? What country was it likely from? Feel free to add this information into your question.

I finally found the movie. It was Antitrust from 2001. Tim Robbins' character has an office with four windowed terrariums in the wall. Each window represents a season and contains a bonsai. 

Was it Duplicity? Here's a screenshot showing the office bonsai in that movie:

And there's a scene where he is pruning the tree, picking up needles, etc. 
It's not a computer movie, but is a spy thriller with some technology components.

no, like I said the bonsai is in a display. behind glass. The office is fairly dark, if I remember correctly.

This sounds like Rising Sun starring Wesley Snipes and Sean Connery. From IMDB:

At the offices of a Japanese corporation, during a party, a woman, who's evidently a professional mistress, is found dead, apparently after some rough sex. A police detective, Web Smith is called in to investigate but before getting there, he gets a call from someone who instructs him to pick up John Connor, a former police Captain and expert on Japanese affairs. When they arrive there Web thinks that everything is obvious but Connor tells him that there's a lot more going on.

While I am not positive about the bonsai, but the rest of your description makes sense. There is a portion of the movie where they are looking at some surveillance footage from the room where the lady died, but through further investigation, they discovered there was some "photo-chopping" going on with it. This scene happened in a very "un-lit" room. Seeing as how this movie is steeped in Japanese culture, a bonsai surely could have been present in a dark room.

No, it wasn't Rising Sun. It was a tech movie based on the west coast of the USA.
